# 230V mains back up with 12V battery and inverter

Tags: batteries, inverter, backup

I am looking to have a 12V battery back up if 230V is lost, to supply a mobile router for security cameras (solar charged battery powered) outside a house when vacant.

I have a 130Ah battery in a battery box and will buy a small inverter (small load for router.)

I'm wondering what I need to disconnect from mains supply and connect to inverter after a mains power loss.

Also, it would be ideal to have a system where the battery is trickle charged when mains supply is available.

What is required, in addition to the battery and inverter?

Comment: This isn't a shopping site; it's an electrical design engineering site.

Comment: Yep, I have edited my post, thanks Andy.

Comment: The simplest way is the minimal-thought way i.e. AC->charger->battery->router.

Comment: Routers rarely need more than 12V so you can probably lose the inverter.

Comment: Thanks Andy aka and Finbarr. Could I use a solar panel and battery, to use a system isolated from mains altogether?

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind your solar panel has to provide enough power in daylight to operate the router AND charge the battery up enough to operate the router through the absence of daylight. Most people drastically underestimate this.

Comment: Is the battery charged with solar power also, or does it depend on mains only for charging?